# Restrict access using SSL certs

Tags: apache, ssl, cpanel

is there a way to restrict access to a website, running Apache via cPanel, using SSL (like CTLs on IIS/Windows)?

I.E, the user has to have an ssl certificate installed/issued to be able to access the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is certainly possible, through the [SSLRequire](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire) directive. The most trivial setup is to formulate `%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} eq "SUCCESS"`. This also requires settting SSLVerifyClient and SSLCACertificatePath, as well as to install the trusted CA certificates.

Comment: I understand that all that does is ensure that content is delivered over HTTPS protocol? 

I need something that restricts unless a certificate is provided by end user.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. If you test for SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY, then HTTPS connections will be rejected if the user does not use the certificate provided to him, or does use a certificate whose CA is not in your list of trusted CAs. If you want to further restrict this (e.g. to specific such users), you can also do that in SSLRequire. Don't confuse the option with SSLRequireSSL.